# Geometrically prove that for a point on a diameter...

Tags: geometry, circles, euclidean-geometry

Geometrically prove that for a point on a diameter between the center point and the perimeter of a circle, the distance between this non-center point is the shortest distance to the perimeter.

So $A$ is the center of the circle, $C$ is the point where a diameter intersects the perimeter, and $B$ is a point between $C$ and $A$. Prove geometrically that for any other chord that includes point $B$ but not point $C$ and intersects the perimeter of the circle at $D$, the line $BC$ will always be shorter than line $BD$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) is sufficient enough. From $\triangle ABD$ we get that

$$BD > |AD - AB|.$$

Both $AD$ and $AC$ equal to the radius of the circle so $AD = AC$, and inequality transforms into $BD > |AC - AB|.$

I hope it is clear that $|AC - AB| = BC.$

[image]

Comment: sorry, it's been a long time since I've done geometry so I'm not fully understanding what that string conveys. is the |AD-AB| supposed to be equivalent to |AC-AB|? can you break it down more for me?

Comment: nvm I think I understand it now.